# New windows open when clicking links after making changes in website (layerslider inclusion)

Tags: php, javascript, slider, hyperlink

I have introduced js code for because of the layerslider inclusion on my website. At the beginning it really messed up my site making the logo be moved down and the sections in the website a bit separate. Because of this I deleted many lines of code on pages.css and layout_header.php (my website homepage has 2 php files with layout_footer_php).

Those weren't the only problems I encontered. Now that the layerslider is more or less well integrated I wonder what I have to do get my menu links back to work as they did before. When you click on the menu links they open a new window if you click them from the homepage but not if your click them from the other windows.

Seem like an easy to solve problem, that bad news is I have no idea of coding, my knowledge is based on try and fail.

my site is http://dtraffic.biz

Thanks in advance

Comment: Me too ;) you had your site in brackets

Answer (score 0):

Your links on the homepage are like this

```
<a href="http://www.dtraffic.biz/surf-ads" target="_blank">
```

and on other pages are like this

```
<a href="http://www.dtraffic.biz/surf-ads">
```

The `target="_blank"` is what is putting it in a new window/tab, you should remove this. See the 'link targets' section of [this page](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/links.php) for info on this.

Comment: Actually they are not, the are only two target="_blank" in layout_header.php as it was before and those links should work like that but no the other ones. This happens since I inserted the layerslider. Code is the same but has changed behaviour, that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem by **remove target `_blank` to `_self`** in line no 1498

```
(function($){

        $.fn.setBlank = function(){

            return this.find('a[href*="http:"]').each(function(){
                if(!$(this).attr( 'target' )){
                    **//$(this).attr({ 'target' : '_blank' });**
                }
            }); 
        };
    })
```

Just only comment this code in `plugin.js` that is present in folder of layer slider.
Thanks